# Django: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: django

I receive an error `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`. The reason is when either `transaction.aggregate(Sum('amount'))` or `reward_transaction.aggregate(Sum('amount'))` has no entry yet. I now wonder is the best way to solve that try / except or is there a 'better way' I haven't considered?

views.py:

```
user = request.user
ambassador = user.ambassador_profile
total_collected = ambassador.transaction.aggregate(Sum('amount'))
total_redeemed = ambassador.reward_transaction.aggregate(Sum('amount'))
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ambassador_reference = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        unique=True,
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='ambassador_profile',
    )
    events = models.ManyToManyField(Event)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True
    )

class Transaction(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(  # TODO Marc: One to One?
        Order,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='transaction'
    )
    ambassador = models.ForeignKey(
        Profile,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='transaction'
    )
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name=_("Earned coins")
    )
    updated = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True
    )
```

Comment: could you upload your profile models?

Comment: Sure! I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do calculations with aggregation output and therefore want to convert `None` to `0` and be robust with regard to the presence of the key, you can just use `get` and the `or` operator:

```
total_collected = ambassador.transaction.aggregate(Sum('amount')).get('amount__sum') or 0
```